# How to get code coverage using gb?

Tags: go, code-coverage, build-tools

Running [gb](https://getgb.io/):

```
gb test .../<regex>/... -v
```

works, but running `gb test .../<regex>/... -coverprofile=cover.out` results in:

```
testing: cannot use -test.coverprofile because test binary was not built with coverage enabled
```

while `go test -coverprofile cover.out` works. How to get code coverage using gb as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-coverprofile` flag is not supported in gb yet.

You can check the status at https://github.com/constabulary/gb/issues/367.

There is also a workaround posted there, which you can use.